# Allow On-Prem SMTP Connections to send email to in-Cloud (O365) Distribution List

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

I would like to move many of my on-Prem Distribution lists to ExchanceOnline Distribution Lists/Groups. (Not Microsoft 365 Groups/Teams style Group). Just a Simple Distribution list to be able to manage the Distribution list with MSGraph/ExchangeOnline PowerShell.

My Issue is that when I create the Distribution list in ExchangeOnline Poowershell, the SMTP Connections to the On-Prem Server cannot find the Distribution List to sent the email to.

So I either need to havre the On-Prem Exchange server know that the Distribution group is in the cloud and send it there, or I need the AAD Connect to do a Writebac of the DL.

All of my Microsoft 365 Groups are being written back to On-Prem AD/Exchange, it seems to be the Distribution lists are not being written back.

I want to be able to manage these new DLs in the cloud, but I need my on-Prem server to be able to resolve the address and send to the members/or cloud DL.